# What is the difference among 'good at' and ' in, with,for'?

Tags: meaning

1. He is good at swimming.
2. He is good in swimming.
3. He is good for swimming.
4. He is good with swimming.

What is the difference among 'good at' and ' in, with,for' in the sentence above in meaning?

Comment: good *at/with/for* but *good in*? I don't think so. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: It's more idiomatic to say good at swimming than good in swimming.  He is good for/with swimming seem to be odd.  However, swimming is good for. you is idiomatic.

Answer (score 8):

I've primarily heard "good in" used to reference school classes.

- "At" is generally used for activities (good at chess, good at drawing)
- "In" is used for classes or jobs (good in math class, good in his role, good in his profession)
- "With" is used for objects/things to show that the subject has skill with them (good with numbers, good with tools)
- "For" would seem to implying how the doer is beneficial (answering the question: what is he good for?)