# What's the difference between good in math and good at math?

Tags: grammar, informal-language

I see both forms, but I've seen in one of the answers here that you use "good in math class" and "not good in math", which is probably not quite true, or is it? Which is it?

I was not gonna ask the question, but after seeing the answer I got more confused.

Here's the link:

[What is the difference among 'good at' and ' in, with,for'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95700/what-is-the-difference-among-good-at-and-in-with-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object of **at** is cast as an activity.

The object of **in** is cast as a discipline or subject, an area of knowledge.

We can conceptualize math as a subject, or as an activity involving various kind of calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about someone's ability in some academic or scholastic subject, e.g. Maths, English, Science, etc.,  then you can use either 'good at' or 'good in'. I personally prefer to use 'good at', but I would not think of correcting someone who used 'good in' instead.

If you are talking about someone's routine behaviour in a particular class, then you can use 'good in', e.g. 'He is usually good in Maths class, but he misbehaves in English.' In this case 'English' is just an abbreviated form of "English class'.

It is quite difficult to provide precise rules regarding which preposition you should use after 'good', as there are likely to be exceptions to any rule you formulate. Native English speakers usually use the right combination because they have grown up with the language.